# jQuery body background-image rotator

Tags: jquery, css, background, slider, image-rotation

For a website I am currently designing I would like to have the body background on a rotation of an array of images. I have tried multiple ways i.e. using the fadeIn() and fadeOut() functions but they seem to affect the opacity of the divisions within the body. I also tried using [bgStretcher](http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-jquery-stretch-background-plugin.html) But this caused appearance issues and made the website slow and choppy.

I would preferably like the images to fade in and out.
Help would be appreciated,

[Here's a link to the website](http://danewilson.me/ICT/arlberg/alpha) 
The script file I currently have been modifying is called background.js under the /js/ directory. The file is currently commented out as It is only experimental.
The two current background images are "images/bg/bg1.jpg" and "images/bg/bg2.jpg"

Here is my current code which I am trying to get working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(switchImage, 5000);
    switchImage();

});

function switchImage()
{
$('body').css("background-image", "url(../images/bg/bg2.jpg)").fadeIn(1000);
$('body').css("background-image", "url(../images/bg/bg1.jpg)").fadeOut(1000);
}
```

Once I can figure out how to transition between background images I can simpily add some conditions to change between an array of images.

Cheers, Dane Wilson

Comment: Please post the relevant code, with which you'd like our help, *here in your question*. And, ideally, post a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), otherwise, once the problem's solved, this question has no further use (since the problem code will be corrected/removed from the page you link to).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very simple with this jQuery Plugin: [jQuery Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)
In the demos "Using Backstretch in a Slideshow" is a code-snippet for it.

Comment: This worked the same as bgStretcher which I mentioned above, but the code is a lot smaller and nicer. I figured out what was causing it to be slow and choppy. It was because I was trying to use an overlay PNG which has transparent properties causing rendering issues. I fixed this by saving my images with the pattern overlay pre-applied

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with css3 only. I'll post a fiddle soon.

EDIT: I tried making an animation with keyframes and CSS3's background-size, but apparently they didn't want to work together too well (flickerings). Probably better to look into jQuery then.